# Powershell: Get-AzureADGroupMember doesnt give me the whole list

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I want to sync two AzureAD Groups, so I read out both groups with `Get-AzureADGroupMember`.

The Problem is, I only get 103 People out of the group instead of 615...

What Can I do, to get the whole list out of the groups?

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Comment: I got it, just put -All $True after the Get-AzureADGroupMember

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you need the `-All` parameter. Otherwise there is a limitation on the number of members the Get-AzureADGroupMember will return.

For anyone else running into this issue, the command is like this:

```
(Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'GroupName'" -All $true | Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $true).Count
```

Alternatively, to store the output in variables for later use:

```
$AzureADGroup = Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'GroupName'" -All $true
$AzureADUsers = $AzureADGroup | Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $true
$AzureADGroupCount = $AzureADUsers | Measure-Object
```

See for reference: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory/Azure-AD-Dynamic-Groups-Display-Membership-and-count-members/td-p/69657